# (Py2neo) - How to get end_node of relationship in neo4j database without cypher

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Are there any py2neo instruction to get end node of relationship, i have tried below code but it doesn't work. thank you

```
relmatcher = RelationshipMatcher(graph_db)
for rel in relmatcher.match(start_node=nodeid, r_type="IS_CONNECTED"):
    print("END NODE:",rel.end_node()["name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this way:

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph("http:yourhost")
for rel in graph.match(start_node=nodeid, rel_type="IS_CONNECTED"):
    print("END NODE:",rel.end_node()["name"])
```